# zookeeper status command in windows

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper and I configured three servers in my local host and I started three servers and they got started. But when I checked the status it returns,

```
"JMX enabled by default"
"Using config: "C:\..\zoo.cfg"
```

Unlike linux, it doesn't returns mode as

```
leader or follower
```

Can anyone tell me why

Answer (score 0):

From zookeeper supported platforms documentation:

> Win32 is supported as a development platform only for both server and
>   client.

So it makes sense, that leader selection does not work.

Comment: @jny...we cannot use it in win64 ah